# WPF Relevancy vs HTML

Tags: wpf, web-applications

At work we have an application that we need to update.  It is a fat client that is largely written in Windows Forms with newer parts of it being in WPF.  The main section of this application is a form designer that is implemented with a Web Browser control using HTML.

We need to redesign a large portion of the application and need to generally improve the user experience.  There's a good chance that I will be the one working on this project and I am very familiar with WPF and feel like it would be a very suitable technology to use.  I would plan to remove the old windows forms portions and largely rewrite the application.

However, there has been some discussion of migrating this application to be a web application in a future release.  My coworker was tossing around the idea of trying to redesign the dialogs and application using HTML while still being a fat client.

Does this seem like a reasonable idea?  Is there any kind of design similar to this approach that would support this kind of hybrid application?  Would we be able to realistically create the same kind of user experience using HTML5 / JS that WPF would offer?

The idea of making portable code is enticing, but I have serious concerns about the feasibility of this suggestion.  I know that windows 8 apps support a variety of design options, but this application would be targeted for xp / windows 7.

Comment: Do HTML5 and JavaScript have all the features you need? Are these technologies fast enough for your purposes? Are your users able to use an HTML5-capable browser (some companies force their employees to use some old IE version)? -- If the answer is "Yes" for every question, then switch to HTML5. If you have at least one "No", then don't.

Comment: Most of our clients are on IE8 currently.  This application is currently only internal, and the plans to move it to a web app are longer term, at least a few years away.  I'm currently a little more concerned with the "is it possible and / or reasonable to do this" over the "should we" aspect currently.  I feel like the should we question is a little more black and white as portability and platform compatibility are obvious large benefits.

Comment: IE8 has only basic HTML5 support. Fortunately, there are tons of JavaScript libs out there which support IE8, so I think you have a good chance to be able to implement your app in JavaScript (for example, the form designer could be built on raphael.js). I would definitely try it :)

Comment: Right, we are familiar with the limitations of IE8 and have been urging our clients to upgrade for some time now.  Sorry, perhaps I've been a bit unclear: I'm pretty sure the full transition to a web app is out of the scope of this project for the time being.  What I'm really inquiring about is whether its feasible to try to leverage development for a desktop fat client WPF application with parts of it developed in HTML / JS.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the application audience but I'd say go with Web if it's easy enough and it should be since you're starting from scratch.

I was faced with the same question 3 years ago and I still regret sticking to WPF because the app could have been deployed on tablets if it was a web app.

If your app contains abundant business logic make sure you split that out well, business logic in JS doesn't work well - crappy to debug, difficult to manage over the entire life of the app. Generally expect more difficult development when compared do WPF but with much larger potential audience.